# Why does account name come as System Account when I log in as myself?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have created Sharepoint site with Web Applicaiton App pool account as UserA.
The SiteCollection primary admin is UserB.
If I login the site using UserA, UserB, UserC or UserD; I can see logged in name in top right corner as System Account. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that you set a policy on the web application with your account and assigned it to act as system account.
To check this go to central administration

- Application Management
- Select a web application
- in the ribbon you will see user policy

Now check if you account is listed there.
[image: Policy for Web Application]

If it is listed there then edit this entry and make sure that the checkbox "Operate as System Account" is not checked. [image: Operate as System Account]

Then you should see your normal user account instead of the system. You can also remove the policy because from my point of view it's now good practice to give you personal permissions based on the policies. Farm admins have always the possibility to grant site collection administration rights from the central administration.

Comment: My user policy shows only NT Authority\Local Service

Comment: Nothing more ? Is your user account the same as the application pool account?

Comment: The user was member of the farm administrator account